# USB Bootable gparted supporting Secure Boot

Tags: live-usb, gparted, secure-boot

I want to be able to move and resize partitions on my systems, so I wanted to make a live GParted USB, thing is, it doesn't support Secure Boot, Ubuntu is overkill and takes long to boot (and depending on the version, doesn't always have gparted installed), is there a compact live Linux that would be able to boot on Secure Boot?
Could I just sign the GParted Live bootloader and the kernel with my MOK? Could I do so with several MOKs to work with my multiple computers? Or must I create an MOK that I will enroll on all of my machines?
Disabling secure boot is an option on all my machines, but it's a hassle to get back on since some of them delete the MOKs when disabled.

Comment: This says the latest version supports UEFI Sedure Boot. https://gparted.org/download.php

Comment: Nice, missed that!